# Enforcing check in comments with a pre-formatted comment template

Tags: event-receivers, version-history, check-in, version-comments

I'm looking for a way to force users to enter a comment when checking in a document to a specific library, I'd also like to auto populate the comment window with some content in order to guide users to format their comments appropriately. I think I can force comments on check in with an event handler, but I'm not sure how to pre-format the comment window.
If anyone has any suggestions on any aspect of my issue I'd be happy to listen.
Thanks.
Dave

Comment: Event receiver works as intended; check in comments are now mandatory. Does anyone have a suggestion as to how I can supply the field with some default text?